# Change top bar and font scaling on login screen 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, login-screen

How can I apply font scaling (or just change font size) and top bar scaling at the login screen? I've customized my settings so the to bar is thinner and text is smaller and I don't like that the things are so huge on login screen. Login screen looks fine, complies to my settings if I log out after I've logged in once, but not on the initial load. How can I fix this?